# Why is my dual-boot Ubuntu 20.04 gets super slow while running Docker containers?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04

Good day to you. So as the title says, I have a dual-boot Ubuntu OS with Windows that gets super slow when I run couple of Docker containers. It's like it freezes every now and then; whereas my Windows OS runs pretty fast. Although I didn't try with the same Docker containers running in my Windows system because they are throwing errors while building and it is the very reason why I moved to Linux.

During partition, I allocated around 50gb to the root fs and around 120gb to the home fs. Currently the root has around 11gb left. I recently installed the drivers for my built-in gpu and thought it would fix this. But it didn't. Also please note that my Windows' OS is installed in an SSD but Ubuntu is not. Also, I have 8gb of ram.

Here's the partition info:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           588M  2.5M  586M   1% /run
/dev/sda8        46G   33G   11G  77% /
tmpfs           2.9G   94M  2.8G   4% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop2       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1328
/dev/loop3      249M  249M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
/dev/loop1       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2344
/dev/loop4       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1405
/dev/loop5       66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
/dev/loop7       44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/15177
/dev/loop6      192M  192M     0 100% /snap/postman/176
/dev/loop8       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/558
/dev/loop9      9.5M  9.5M     0 100% /snap/htop/3359
/dev/loop10      45M   45M     0 100% /snap/snapd/15314
/dev/nvme0n1p3  100M   31M   70M  31% /boot/efi
/dev/sda10      140G   10G  123G   8% /home
tmpfs           588M   44K  588M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Here's the cpu info:

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   43 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          8
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-7
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       AuthenticAMD
CPU family:                      23
Model:                           24
Model name:                      AMD Ryzen 5 3400G with Radeon Vega Graphics
Stepping:                        1
CPU MHz:                         1660.831
BogoMIPS:                        7400.28
Virtualization:                  AMD-V
L1d cache:                       128 KiB
L1i cache:                       256 KiB
L2 cache:                        2 MiB
L3 cache:                        4 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-7
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     Not affected
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; LFENCE, IBPB conditional, STIBP disabled, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
```

Someone please suggest what I should do in this regard. Can't afford to buy a new pc now. If you need any other info please tell me what to run.

Comment: *please note that my Windows' OS is installed in an SSD but Ubuntu is not* So, where exactly? If on an HDD then pretty much everything will be slow and any comparison with any other OS in a proper SSD shouldn't be made, it's simply ridiculous. And why the 14.04 and 12.04 tags if you're using 20.04? Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Is the performance difference of installing in an HDD and SSD so big? I mean it is really slow. It's like I'm using a 20 year old machine.

Comment: Yes, the difference if effing HUGE! And as time goes by and OSes are optimized to use the faster SSDs drives the differences will only increase. This is particularly noticeable even when compared the slowest SATA SSD with a typical notebook 5400rpm HDD.

Comment: How many docker containers are you running? 8GB is not a lot of RAM.  If your programs are frequently accessing the hard drive, then a HDD can slow you down. HDDs have to physically seek to different sectors of a drive to access data. If you have several programs all trying to read from different areas of the drive at different time, it is going to cause a huge bottleneck.

Comment: @ChanganAuto So you think I should add an SSD and partition the root fs in SSD and home fs in HDD will help? I was also wondering if the processor is not being utilized properly. Like may be only 1-2 core is working? It's just a hunch and I'm not an engineer.

Comment: @Nmath Ummm around 9 containers. I stop the biggest container which consumes the most resources because it freezes my computer totally. These containers are for the local dev environment for my employer's software.

Comment: From your description this is a hardware problem due to lack of resources.

Comment: @Nmath Yeah. Any suggestion from your side?

Comment: From an OS/Software standpoint, I don't think there is anything you can do. Perhaps you can run a resource monitor on the host OS to see what is suffering more-- RAM or disk access and upgrade your hardware accordingly

Comment: @Nmath You think adding an SSD will help?

Comment: If all of your containers are frequently accessing the hard drive at the same time to the point that the HDD is causing the bottleneck you are experiencing, then yes.  If that's not the problem, and the problem is that you don't have enough RAM, then no.  If the problem is both of those things, then maybe. If the problem is also the CPU, then maybe you need to upgrade all three. It really depends on what resources you need that you don't have

Comment: Thanks @Nmath and ChanganAuto for your suggestions